# Download protected Pdf

Tags: pdf, download

How could I download a protected Pdf (view allowed, download not)? The link of the Pdf file is the following:

http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/handle/1/20399

Comment: Hi @Dave, if I'm not mistaken, it's allow to store an ebook for 24 hours and then it must be deleted. However, if this is not right, I'd learn how download a protected Pdf (not the above Pdf).

Comment: Hi @fixer1234, if is not allowed to store the file for 24 hours, I ask how download a protected file (for example a file which I uploaded).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? I can't figure this question out: I just clicked the big blue button to download/view (that's the same thing) the pdf.

Comment: @MarcksThomas, are you able to save that PDF to your computer

Comment: @Dave: Of course.

Comment: Hi @MarcksThomas, please show me another solution to obtain the same result. My goal is to learn many ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, please screen shot that... I can view it, but I can't download it

Comment: @Dave: As you wish, though there's really no magic to it. https://snag.gy/mWucHG.jpg

Comment: @MarcksThomas What kind of browser are you using???

Comment: @MarcksThomas, strange.  I also don't get that option.  It simply opens in a viewer, with no access to anything downloadable.  It seems the question asks the wrong thing.  If the download option is visible to some people, the file isn't protected.  The question is how to access that option, and why it isn't visible on some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have permission and are not breaking any laws.

The link you want is

```
http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/20399/1/24441.pdf
```

However, you should not access it if you don't have permission.

The way to locate this is to use a browser with dev tools (most do). In this case, in Chrome press <kbd>F12</kbd>

Then in the `Elements` tab you can locate the link URL by expanding the HTML elements until you find the relevant section.

**Update**

Another way is to disable the PDF viewer in the browser (this is unlikely to work for the website in your question but may work for other websites). This means that when the PDF is requested, the browser has no tool/method to open the file, and as such will provide it as a download.

Comment: Hi @Dave, in the section Elements, where did you find the link http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/20399/1/24441.pdf? I opened all subsections in the Elements section, but I don't see that.

Comment: It is in there @GennaroArguzzi :)

Comment: Disabling the browser's PDF viewer is clever.  But in this case, the viewer is something built into the web site rather than the local viewer.

Comment: @fixer1234 I will make this clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, and thanks for this post I am able to get a clue to its solution. The steps are as follows:

1. Open the Acrobat Reader application on your PC
2. Try to open a file using Ctrl-O shortcut or File-->Open in the pull-down menu
3. In the Filename text box in the dialog box that appears, paste the URL of the protected online PDF file
4. Click the Open button and wait for the file to be downloaded and opened on your PC-based Acrobat Reader

It worked on me!

Answer (score 0):

The straigtforward (but probably not entirely satisfying) way to do that is to install a plugin that lets you print as pdf when you press Ctrl+P. Then you just print the whole page as pdf from your browser. Usually works like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

Download & Install Git from https://git-scm.com/

On the View page for the pdf press F12 to open the inspector.
search "iframe" until you find iframe Value with bitstream.
Copy the value

Launch Git and type the following code:

curl 'https://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/xxx' -H 'keyname: Akz914723960' -H 'Type: application/pdf' -d '' -o C:/name.pdf

Replace the copied value with bistream in place of  xxx in the above code.

Replace "name" with the file name you want to give the pdf ... it will download to your C drive folder.

Comment: How is Git relevant to this answer?

Comment: @Joseph, Thanks for pointing that out. Have edited my answer on what is to be done in git. Git is used to run the download command script.

Comment: Hi, I think there is a misunderstanding here. Git is in no way needed to run a command like `curl` — they are separate software. On Windows, one can simply launch `cmd` to run these commands, and on a Mac, one would launch Terminal. Git is not needed to run commands.